# Is Hurwitz's theorem true in constructive mathematics?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, constructive-mathematics, division-algebras

Hurwitz's theorem says that the only division composition algebras over the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ are the real numbers themselves $\mathbb{R}$, the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$, and the octonions $\mathbb{O}$. However, in pure constructive mathematics without any weak axiom of choice, the notion of the set of real numbers bifurcates into multiple incompatible notions, such as the Cauchy real numbers $\mathbb{R}_C$, the Dedekind real numbers $\mathbb{R}_D$, the Escardó-Simpson real numbers $\mathbb{R}_E$, and the MacNeille real numbers $\mathbb{R}_M$, and I'd imagine the same for $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{H}$, and $\mathbb{O}$ (i.e. Cauchy complex numbers, Dedekind quaternions, etc). For which of these sets of real numbers, complex numbers, quaternions, and octanions, if any at all, does Hurwitz's theorem still hold true?

---

Edit: Swapped out "normed division algebra" for "division composition algebra" for the following reason:

Classically, Hurwitz's theorem is also expressed in terms of finite-dimensional normed division algebras over that set of real numbers. However, finite-dimensional normed divison algebras and division composition algebras over the real numbers do not coincide in constructive mathematics because there are multiple different types of real numbers in constructive mathematics.

In a division composition algebra, the norm $\lvert a \rvert := \langle a, a\rangle$ has a codomain of the ground field.

However, that is not necessarily true of finite-dimensional normed division algebras over some field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}_X$ in constructive mathematics, because the notion of "multiplicative norm" bifurcates into multiple definitions based upon which set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}_Y$ is used as the codomain of the norm. It is perhaps more appropriate to call them finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}_Y$-normed division $\mathbb{R}_X$-algebras. One can have a finite-dimensional normed division $\mathbb{R}_C$-algebra with a norm valued in $\mathbb{R}_D$, where $\mathbb{R}_C$ are the Cauchy real numbers and $\mathbb{R}_D$ are the Dedekind real numbers, but such a finite-dimensional normed division algebra is not a composition algebra, and is not covered under Hurwitz's theorem.

Thus, for sets of real numbers $\mathbb{R}_X$ and $\mathbb{R}_Y$, every division composition $\mathbb{R}_X$-algebra for some set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}_X$ is a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}_X$-normed division $\mathbb{R}_X$-algebra, but a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}_Y$-normed division $\mathbb{R}_X$-algebra is only a division composition $\mathbb{R}_X$-algebra if $\mathbb{R}_Y$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}_X$.

Comment: I don't know about constructive math, but you can algebraically construct models of $\mathbb C$, $\mathbb H$ and $\mathbb O$ over $\mathbb R$, in a way that works over quite general fields, e.g., adjoin a square root of $-1$ to get $\mathbb C$.  I imagine this would work over any of those notions of real numbers.

Comment: Could the theorem be weakened to saying that every normed unital $\mathbb R$-algebra (for some version of $\mathbb R$) embeds into some version of the octonions?

Comment: @Kimball, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417101/hurwitzs-theorem-in-constructive-mathematics#comment1070563_417101), isn't the point not just "is there *a* model of $\mathbb C$, $\mathbb H$, and $\mathbb O$ constructively?"—certainly yes—but rather "are there perhaps accidentally several constructively *distinct* models of $\mathbb C$, $\mathbb H$, and $\mathbb O$?"

Comment: I really don't think this result is going to be very sensitive to having different versions of $\mathbb{R}$. There's a different version of Hurwitz's theorem that's about composition algebras and has no assumptions on the ground field at all.  For example, surely Hurwitz's theorem is fine classically for any real closed field?

Comment: @NoahSnyder There is an assumption on the ground field, namely that in a division composition algebra the norm returns values in the ground field, while that's not necessarily true of normed division algebras over a certain set of real numbers. I think this shows more that one cannot use normed division algebras to define Hurwitz's theorem, and one has to use division composition algebras.

Comment: @LSpice Sure, but my naive conception is that finite algebraic extensions won't differ in constructive math (except I guess the OP gave the "wrong" formulation of Hurwitz's theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a weakening of Hurwitz's theorem that is true constructively, with essentially the same proof:

Let $A$ be a division composition algebra. Then any chain of proper subalgebras $\mathbb{R} = A_0 \subsetneq A_1 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq A_n = A$ has length $n \leq 3$ (where "proper" means "contains an element with positive distance from the previous algebra).

We can also show that in general, any inclusion of subalgebras generated by adding one element must come from (a quotient of) the [General Cayley-Dickson construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction#General_Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction) with parameter $\cdot \gamma$, $\gamma \leq 0$.

Comment: (I strongly suspect that we can get the full theorem constructively, but doing so requires a lemma that if $B \subseteq A$ is a proper finite-dimensional subalgebra then there are enough nice $j \in A \setminus B$ with $\langle B \cup \{j\}\rangle \subseteq A$ finite dimensional, and I haven't been able to prove it.)